# Save checkbox status in one cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox

I have this code:

```
$("input.box[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if ($.cookie(name) && $.cookie(name) == "true") {
        $(this).prop('checked', $.cookie(name));
    }
});

$("input.box[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $.cookie(name, $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    });
});
```

and html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="smth1" />something1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="smth2" />something2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="smth3" />something3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="smth4" />something4<br />

<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="anthr1" />anotherthing1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="anthr2" />anotherthing2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="anthr3" />anotherthing3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="anthr4" />anotherthing4<br />

<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="new1" />newthing1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="new2" />newthing2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="new3" />newthing3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="new4" />newthing4<br />

etc etc
```

This makes cookie for every checkbox. What I want to do is save checkboxes status  in only one cookie. I'd appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: I see you passed checkbox's name as cookie's name. Either make all the checkboxes to share a common name, or pass a static name to your cookie.

Comment: if you not deal with that cookie and its value on server side then I highly recommend using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

Comment: what do you mean common name? @31piy i'll look into localStorage thanks! if anyone has a demo that would really help